# asp linkbutton cssclass selecting using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have three `linkbuttons` when the user selects the current link it should be red.but at present it even makes the visited link also red which should not be the case.can any one help regarding this?

```
<li>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCat1" runat="server" 
OnClick="lnkCat1_Click" CssClass="mylink" 
OnClientClick="return changeColor();"></asp:LinkButton></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeColor(e) {
        e.style.color = "red";
        }              
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

Please include jquery first

css

```
.red {
     color: red;
}
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(e) {
        $('.red').removeClass('red');
        $(e).addClass("red"); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is raw javascript code, i.e. you don't need libraries like jQuery.

```
<li>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCat1" runat="server" 
OnClick="lnkCat1_Click" CssClass="mylink" 
OnClientClick="return changeColor(this); return false;"></asp:LinkButton></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeColor(e) {
     e.style.color = "red";
  }              

</script>
```

this line

```
OnClientClick="return changeColor(this); return false;"
```

will pass the link element to the javascript function `changeColor`, and immediately `return false`, so the link's default action (visiting another page) never happens. (this may be different for IE)

your actual function also had an extra `}` in it.

I'd use something like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools, so you can view javascript errors as they appear